# Is debugging HTML in Firefox or Chrome really this hard?

Tags: html, debugging, firefox, google-chrome, firebug

How can I use firebug or the Chrome debugger to debug html?
It seems like it should be easy but I don't see how to do it?

For example, I have `<script poo="text/javascript" src="../src/JSTweener.js"></script>` and the debugger in no way picks up that there is an error because I had `poo` in the `script` tag. How can I debug stuff like this? Thanks.

Comment: The property like `poo` here are called "expando" DOM properties. They're not a part of specification od HTML/XML/whatever doctype, but still, they *can* be used (and _are_ hugely used by JavaScript-heavy applications) to store some additional data for the nodes. You can set them in HTML markup, and read/write using JavaScript (though with a little bit different syntax).

Answer (score 2):

[Try out the W3C HTML Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Use an html validator to pick up problems in the actual markup. Both ie developer toolbar and firebug have validation Iirc. Remember it's markup not imperative code so the concept of debugging is the wrong idiom.